# Connection times out when trying to use HTML form and PHP to read from different files

Tags: php, html, forms, post, web

I'm setting up a gallery where the content of gallery.php depends on the POST data sent to it. The page first retrieves the filename of entry at line number $pagenumber in CanvasList.txt, then it gets the content of that file. If no POST data was sent, it defaults to $pagenumber = 0. The page loads when it is accessed without sending POST data, but when I use the form, the connection times out. Why is this? Here's some of my code:

```
<div class='formbox'>
<form class='navigator' method='POST' action='https://www.mydomain.com/gallery.php'>
<input type='text' name='pagenumber' value='pagenumber'>
<input type='submit' id='gotopage' value='Go'>
</div>

<?php

$input = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($input == 'POST') {
    $pagenumber = (int)$_POST['pagenumber'];
} else {
    $pagenumber = 0;
}

$list = "gallery/CanvasList.txt";
$lines = file($list, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$filename = $lines[$pagenumber]; 
$canvasHandle = fopen('gallery/' . $filename, 'r');

//getting and processing content (works)
```

I tried changing the default value of $pagenumber, but same result.

Comment: How can you be sure that the connection timed out?

Comment: Error in FireFox window "the connection has timed out" after the status bare has been at "Connecting to [...]" for a minute or so

Answer (score 0):

changed

```
action='https://www.mydomain.com/gallery.php'
```

to

```
action='gallery.php'
```

That solved it. I'm not allowed to accept my own answer before in two days, on 23/1/14. If someone else is allowed to, I encourage them to mark this Answer as accepted.